# Unable to fetch source and target branches of a Pull Request - Azure Devops

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-devops-services

I have my source code repository in github and my pipeline in Azure devops. I am trying to execute certain tasks in my pipeline based on the source branch of a pull request. The pipeline gets triggered on PR. However, when I try to get the below attributes of a Pull request from my yml pipeline, I get the message shown in the screenshot below. It basically states **command not found** for all the values. Is there anything obvious that could cause this. Or is this not how these values are expected to be fetched? Any help is much appreciated.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - feature/azure-pipeline
    - develop
    - release/*
    exclude:
    - features/*
    - master
pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - main

stages:

  - stage: TestStage 
    jobs:

    - job: unit_test
      displayName: 'Unit test Job'
      pool:
       vmImage: 'macos-latest'
      

      variables:
      - name: currentBranch
        ${{ if eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
         value: $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
        ${{ if ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest') }}:
         value: $(Build.SourceBranch)

      steps:
      - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
        displayName: 'Download CSSM secrets'
        name: secureKeys
        inputs:
          secureFile: 'cssmkeys.properties'
      - script: |
         echo Target Branch is $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)
         echo Source Repository URI is $(System.PullRequest.SourceRepositoryURI)    
         echo PullRequest Id is $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)
         echo Source Branch is $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)   
         echo Current Branch is $(value)
```

**Output screenshot**
[image]

**EDIT**
Link to the system variables page - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Did you check the documentation for what system variables are available in this scenario? Where do you have the PR behavior defined in your YAML?

Comment: Yes, updated the question with the link @DanielMann

Comment: You're using a POSIX-style shell for your command here (note that this has nothing to do with Git, it's strictly up to whatever is interpreting the YAML here). That shell is trying to *execute* `$(foo)` as the *command* foo; to expand a variable, you'd need `$foo` or `${foo}`, but dots are not valid in variable names in POSIX shells.

Comment: The link you've added mention that to get PowerShell invoked you must use `powershell` (not `script`) in your YAML.

Comment: - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            # Write your PowerShell commands here.
            Write-Host "Hello World"
            Write-Host "$(Build.SourceBranch)"
            Write-Host "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

Comment: Hello World
refs/heads/develop
System.PullRequest.SourceBranch: /Users/runner/work/_temp/6cdb0545-33ad-4846-92b1-fa518c861b77.ps1:6
Line |
   6 |  Write-Host "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"
     |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'System.PullRequest.SourceBranch' is not recognized
     | as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
     | included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @torek - I have tried powershell, still the same error

Comment: I don't use Windows and don't really know anything about PowerShell, so all I can tell you is that `${var.i.able}` is not valid in POSIX shells. Reading that same documentation page you linked, though, I note the following quote: `In YAML pipelines, you can reference predefined variables as environment variables. For example, the variable Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory becomes the variable BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY.`

Comment: Based on these samples, that documentation seems not to be particularly good quality, but you should probably read it very closely anyway.